# MySQL: I omitted a space--what did I do?

Tags: mysql

I'm curious and learning...this is non-urgent

On a production server running 19 databases I entered this typo

```
mysql -uroot-p[passwd]
            ^ omitted space
```

I soon enjoyed a solid 12 seconds of Shark-Eats-Quint-Grade elevated heart rate:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
```

I've confirmed this typo as harmless** but now am curious how this yielded output rather than error.

My SQL-Fu grows but is not yet very strong.  I clearly attempted authentication with the unintentional user `root-ppasswd`, but with neither password passed to mysql nor existing true credentials I'd have expected the command to fail--did this spawn a new theoretical DB instance awaiting its chance to be permanently written?

** Please allow me to preempt those inclined to stress the danger of premature engagement with the <enter> key.  Yes--hollowpoint ducked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's treating the whole string as the username  and without a password the MySQL client is logging you in as anon.

```
mysql -usomerandomstring
mysql> SELECT CURRENT_USER();
+----------------+
| CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+
| @localhost     |
+----------------+
```

Comment: Okay, so I was correct about submitting a fabricated userID.  My initial guess was close but didn't lead me far enough around the corner.  Does this mean I'm logged in as a user who's simply not authorized to view anything good?

Comment: From the manual: By default, a MySQL installation has an anonymous user, allowing anyone to log into MySQL without having to have a user account created for them. This is intended only for testing, and to make the installation go a bit smoother. You should remove them before moving into a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

### update

I knew I'd risk learning something here. :-)

Didn't want to preclude upvotes on harvey's helpful answer but address fellow SQL noobs...

As harvey mentioned, I've tripped over anonymous login.  My manual doesn't reference anonymous user--not that I read its entirety before posting or even knew what to seek, which is why web search quickly yielded to ServerFault.

I found [this advice on removing anon login](http://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/remove-anonymous-user-from-mysql/), coming soon to a non-work day near you:

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='';
```

Comment: In general, you should find a bunch of hardening guides before putting a new major piece of infrastructure online.

Comment: You're of course correct, but I inherited all this infrastructure and am striving to best play the hand I'm dealt. I proceed and add pieces to the puzzle.  Thanks for the tip.